# Need to retrieve all files Urls ,which are stored in google cloud bucket using node.js functions(All files )

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

How can i retrieve all files which are stored in google cloud bucket. (ALL FILES)?

Thanks and Regards,
Tapas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **solution** that I have tested using a *Node.js 8* **HTTP Cloud Function**. You can use it for the reference and modify it according to your needs:

My **index.js** file:

```
exports.listFiles = async(req, res) => {
  let bucketName = req.body.bucket || req.query.bucket
  
  // Import the Google Cloud Storage library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Initiate a Storage client
  const storage = new Storage();

  // List files in the bucket and store their name in the array called 'result'
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  let result = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    result.push(file.name);
  });

  // Send the result upon a successful request
  res.status(200).send(result);
};
```

My **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

---

## How to call it:

It can be called via the **URL** provided for triggering the function, by appending that URL with `/?bucket=<name-of-your-bucket>`:

```
https://<function-region>-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>/?bucket=<name-of-the-bucket>
```

Alternatively, it can also be called using **curl**:

```
 curl --data "bucket=<name-of-your-bucket>" https://<functions-region>-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<function-name>
```

---

## Sample Output:

```
["test-file-1.txt","test-file-2.png","test-file-3.png","test-file-4.png"]
```

---

## EDIT:

Here's how you can change the **index.js** file to get the **URLs** instead of the filenames:

```
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  let result = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    result.push("https://storage.cloud.google.com/" + bucketName + "/" + file.name);
  });
```

The whole **index.js** file:

```
exports.listFiles = async(req, res) => {
  let bucketName = req.body.bucket || req.query.bucket

  // Import the Google Cloud Storage library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Initiate a Storage client
  const storage = new Storage();

  // List files in the bucket and store their name in the array called 'result'
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  let result = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    result.push("https://storage.cloud.google.com/" + bucketName + "/" + file.name);
  });

  // Send the result upon a successful request
  res.status(200).send(result);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the names of the files in a bucket, Denis T. has written a great answer.

If you want to list **the URLs** corresponding to the files and **your bucket is protected by some read access security rules**, you can use the [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method of the [`File`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html) object: it will return a signed URL which allows **limited time access to the file**. For more info, have a look at the [Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client API Reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/index.html).

You don't indicate in your question how you want to call this Cloud Function. One standard way is to use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), that is called form the client (Web, iOS, Android).

Here is the full code of a Cloud Function that will return an array of all the signed URLs corresponding to the files in you default bucket.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount/yourprojectname-firebase-adminsdk-jr6wt-d00765e1eb");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: 'yourprojectname.appspot.com'
});


exports.listSignedURLs = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const [files] = await admin.storage().bucket().getFiles();

    const promises = [];

    const options = {
        version: 'v2', // defaults to 'v2' if missing.
        action: 'read',
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 // one hour for example
    };

    files.forEach(file => {
        promises.push(file.getSignedUrl(options));
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);

});
```

Note that we need to generate a private key file for the service account. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#set-up-project-and-service-account) for more detail. We save the JSON private key file in a specific folder under the `functions` folder (i.e. `serviceAccount` in the example above) and we use it when initializing the Admin SDK.

After deployment, you can call this function as follows from a Web client:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>

//.....

const listSignedURLs = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listSignedURLs');
listSignedURLs().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

You will find more detail on how to call it from an Android or iSO app [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).